# Putting a caption and an image inside of a centered div that slides down from the top of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a gallery in HTML/CSS/jQuery. I have a bunch of thumbnails that all represent different images of varying sizes and orientations. When the thumbnail is clicked, I want the image to slide down from the top of the screen. The image should be as large as possible but still fitting in the window, taking into account margins and the like.

I have gotten all this to work properly in the past. However, now I want to add a caption below the image.

My solution was this. I have a div container that is fixed and is positioned with top:-96% and bottom:100% When a thumbnail is clicked, jQuery moves that to top:2% and bottom:2%

Previously I had a border that surrounded the image. Now I want to make that border actually part of a div instead, so that the border can go around the caption which should be below the image and centered, and said image.

Nothing I am doing is working, however. The image will not fit into the viewport, and will always be its max size no matter what I change the percent to.

I'm completely lost, I have no idea how to make this all work out. If you need code, I can give it to you, but as I said, it doesn't work. Thank you all in advance.

EDIT: Added code

HTML:

```
<div id=imgHoverCont>
    <div id=imgBg>
        <img id=imgHover src="" alt="">
        <div id=commentHover></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#imgHoverCont{
    text-align:center;
    position:fixed;
    left:2%;
    right:2%;
    top:-96%;
    bottom:100%;
}

#imgHover{
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
}

#imgBg{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}

#commentHover{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    color:black;
    background-color:white;
}
```

JS: Thumbnails are stored in an array of objects with their ID and their source.

```
for(let i in thumbnails){
       $(thumbnails[i].id).on("click",function(livingHell){
           return function(){
               $("#imgHover").attr("src",thumbnails[livingHell].src)
               $("#imgHoverCont").css("display","block");
               $("#commentHover").html(thumbnails[livingHell].comment);
               $("#imgHoverCont").animate({bottom:"2%",top:"2%"},1000);
           }
       }(i));
   };
```

Comment: Hi, it's customary in SO to show what you've tried, so code will be good.

Comment: it sounds like you need to change the `img` positioning inside the div to `initial`, then it will be affected by the size of the `fixed` div

Answer (score 1):

I've made some changes to your CSS
if I understood your question it works like expected, look here: https://jsfiddle.net/cratgjks/

```
#imgHoverCont{
    text-align:center;
    position:fixed;
    left:2%;
    right:2%;
    top:-96%;
    bottom:100%;
    width:100%; /*new rule*/
}

#imgHover{
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;/*changed rule*/
}

#imgBg{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width:100%;/*changed rule*/
    max-height:100%;
    width:1500px
}

#commentHover{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    color:black;
    background-color:white;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesn't work. It also doesn't work on JSfiddle either for me.

Comment: could you be more specific? in the fiddle, when I press the "hey" button a picture floats down at 100% width with a caption centred underneath it - is this happening for you? is this not what you wanted?

Comment: Maybe I'm just using JSFiddle wrong, but when I resize the viewing window the image starts display wrong even after refreshing the page. Nor does it work on my webpage. The image seems to always display at full size with no regard for the size of the container. I would also like it to be 100% width OR height depending on the orientation, so that it fits in the screen no matter what the size is

Comment: okay, I get you now - so first of all, I've changed `#imgBg` a bit, set `max-width` to `100%` and width to `1500px` (go as wide as you'd like) - so it always works as far as width. As to making it responsive (that's what you're asking) - I think you'll have to use `media-query`